# Mean, Median and Mode of a QVector

Tags: c++, collections, statistics, vectors, qt

I would like some help condensing this code down to size. I am trying to utilize Qt's container classes as efficiently as possible. I do not believe this code reflects my objective.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QVector<int> vect;

    vect.append(0);
    vect.append(0);
    vect.append(0);
    vect.append(0);
    vect.append(1);
    vect.append(1);
    vect.append(2);
    vect.append(1);

    QVectorIterator<int> ivect(vect);

    double median = 0;
    if(vect.count() % 2 == 0){

        median =
        static_cast<double>((vect[vect.count() / 2 - 1] + vect[vect.count() / 2])) / 2;
    }
    else{

        median = vect[vect.count() / 2];
    }

    int sum = 0;
    while(ivect.hasNext()){

        sum += ivect.next();
    }

    double mean = static_cast<double>(sum) / vect.count();

    QSet<int> set;

    ivect.toFront();
    while(ivect.hasNext())
    {
        set << ivect.next();
    }

    QMap<int, int> map;

    QSetIterator<int> iset(set);

    ivect.toFront();
    while(iset.hasNext())
    {
        int count = 0;
        while(ivect.hasNext())
        {
            if(iset.peekNext() == ivect.next())
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        ivect.toFront();
        map.insert(iset.next(), count);
    }

    QMapIterator<int, int> imap(map);

    int maxValue = 0;
    QString mode;
    while(imap.hasNext())
    {
        imap.next();
        if(imap.value() > maxValue)
        {
           maxValue = imap.value();
           mode = QString::number(imap.key());
        }
        else if(imap.value() == maxValue)
        {
            mode = "NULL";
        }
    }

    qDebug() << set;
    qDebug() << map;
    qDebug() << "Mean:" << mean;
    qDebug() << "Median:" << median;
    qDebug() << "Mode frequency:" << maxValue;
    qDebug() << "Mode:" << mode;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have decided to use Qt, but that doesn't mean you must forsake all that standard C++ has to offer.
Actually, Qt does its best to be as compatible as possible, just to make that possible.

So, let's see:

1. Use an initializer-list for the vector.
2. Don't be afraid of using a conditional-operator where it makes things easier or at least shorter without becoming cryptic.
3. `const`-qualifying as much as possible helps catch errors.
4. Your median-calculation (though not the median with that example-data) is wrong, you have to sort first.
5. You really want to accumulate in a `double` using the standard algorithm, for brevity and correctness. As a bonus, you can make it `const` too.
6. As the vector is sorted, the problem of finding the mode is equivalent to finding the longest consecutive run, which can be solved far more efficiently than with a map.
7. `median` and `mean` assume a non-empty input, not so `mode`, though that will only calculate the first mode.

(I only proved it right, I didn't run it.)

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QVector<int> vect = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1 };
    std::sort(vect.begin(), vect.end());
    const auto median = vect.size()%2
        ? vect[vect.size() / 2]
        : ((double)vect[vect.size() / 2 - 1] + vect[vect.size() / 2]) * .5;
    const auto mean = std::accumulate(vect.begin(), vect.end(), .0) / vect.size();
    const auto mode = [&]{
        size_t bestC = 0, tmpC = 0;
        int    bestV = 0, tmpV = 0;
        auto apply = [&](int next){
            if(tmpC > bestC)
                bestC = tmpC, bestV = tmpV;
            tmpC = 1, tmpV = next;
        };
        for(int x : vect)
            if(c == tmpV)
                tmpC++;
            else
                apply(x);
        apply(0);
        return bestC ? QString::number(bestV) : "NULL";
    }();
    qDebug() << "Mean:" << mean;
    qDebug() << "Median:" << median;
    qDebug() << "Mode:" << mode;
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: `accululate` is defined in `numeric`

Answer (score 4):

**Sorted vs Unsorted**

Your `QVector` sequence contains an unsorted sequence of values.  Your median calculation has a precondition that your sequence is sorted.  Consider the sequence `1, 0, 1`, what is the median?

**Small, Focused, and Testable Functions**

Prefer writing functions that employ the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).  Splitting out median and testing it with different sequence types would have pointed out a problem. How about calculating the mean of an empty container? Is division by zero a problem?

**Standard Algorithms**

Being able to understand when you should use standard algorithms and applying them is very important.  Mean can be written using `std::accumulate()`.  Median can be written in terms of `std::nth_element()`.  Mode can be written using `boost::bimap` (or utilize `std::unordered_map`+`std::multimap`) and `std::upper_bound()` with `std::transform()` to return the modes of a sequence.  Not all sequences are uni-modal.